# Can you define functions in settings.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build

In the `settings.gradle` file that accompanies the root `build.gradle` file in a Gradle project, can you define functions that can be used in all sub-`build.gradle` files in the project?

Comment: after writing this question i think the best way to do this is to probably put it in the root build.gradle file if it is a function... and in gradle.properties if it is a nvp property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to define functions in `settings.gradle` that can be reused later on in subprojects. As you can see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#gsc.tab=0) `Settings` object has no access to `Project` instances (only `ProjectDescriptor` which is just a kind of a description). Also `Project` (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html)) has no access to `Settings`. So they cannot interchange the content.

What you can to is to define functions in root `Project` (as in your comment) or move the stuff to `stuff.gradle` and apply it in every single script you need the content it provides.

Comment: Could you do a mix of the 2 and put your functions in a stuff.gradle and apply it to allprojects in the top level build.gradle file?

Comment: @Klunk it seems it is doable.

Comment: Yep confirms my suspicions. works fine the way you suggested.

Comment: Can the "settings.gradle" reach the build.gradle file of the project, to access some function in it? If so, how?